# Convert pandas.groupby to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, group-by

Consider, dataframe `d`:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  'b': [2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
                  'c': [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2]})
>   a   b   c
0   0   2   1
1   2   1   0
2   1   0   2
3   1   1   1
4   1   0   0
5   1   0   2
6   1   2   2
```

I want to split it by column `a` into dictionary like that:

```
{0:    a  b  c
    0  0  2  1,

 1:    a  b  c
    2  1  0  2
    3  1  1  1
    4  1  0  0
    5  1  0  2
    6  1  2  2,

 2:    a  b  c
    1  2  1  0}
```

The solution I've found using `pandas.groupby` is:

```
{k: table for k, table in d.groupby("a")}
```

What are the other solutions?

Comment: I think the one you have is an elegant one. Why are you not satisfied?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `dict` with `tuple` / `list` applied on your `groupby`:

```
res = dict(tuple(d.groupby('a')))
```

A memory efficient alternative to `dict` is to create a `groupby` object and then use [`get_group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html):

```
res = d.groupby('a')
res.get_group(1)  # select dataframe where column 'a' = 1
```

In cases where the resulting table requires a minor manipulation, like resetting the index, or removing the groupby column, continue to use a dictionary comprehension.

```py
res = {k: v.drop('a', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True) for k, v in d.groupby('a')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d.groupby('a').apply(lambda dd:dd.to_dict('i')).to_dict()
```

ouput：

```
{0: {0: {'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}},
 1: {2: {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 2},
  3: {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1},
  4: {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0},
  5: {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 2},
  6: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}},
 2: {1: {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}}}
```